# Array sort reverse order. Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I am trying to make a array to print everything in reverse order. I get this error:

> The error: side535Opg15.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
>   Arrays(mArray.reverseOrder());
>   symbol:   method reverseOrder()
>   location: variable mArray of type int[]
>   1 error

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class side535Opg15{

   public static void main(String[] args){

   int[] a1 = {2,7,6,5,1,9};

   int[] mArray = printBackwards(a1);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mArray));
   Arrays.sort(mArray);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mArray));
   Arrays.sort(mArray.reverseOrder());
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mArray));

   }

   public static int[] printBackwards(int[] a1){
      int[] aFinal = new int[a1.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++){
      aFinal[i]=a1[i];

      }
      return aFinal;
   }
}
```

Comment: obvioiusly an array does not have a `reverseOrder()` method. perhaps you meant `java.util.Collections.reverseOrder()`? perhaps you need to google how to sort an array in reverse order? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_reverseorder.htm

Answer (score -2):

You have not written reverseOrder() method that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: that is not the problem. well, technically it is, but how do you suggest OP writes a method for an immutable java.lang class ?? if OP wants to sort an array in reverse order, there is a way to do it in Java, and it does not involve writing a method for `array`

Comment: you can implement comparator interface to provide sorting logic.

Comment: ex: Arrays.sort(mArray,Comparator<YourLogicClass>).

Comment: thanks very much. but once again, sorting an array in reverse natural order of elements does not require implementing a Comparator